# Apache CXF 3.0.4 and Wss4j, issue with KeyIdentifier EncryptedKeySHA1

Tags: security, encryption, cxf, wss4j

I'm using CXF 3.0.4 to encrypt a Webservice, and I want the KeyIdentifier to be set to EncryptedKeySHA1. To do so, I added the parameters `<entry key="encryptionKeyIdentifier" value="EncryptedKeySHA1"></entry>` to the context.xml in the WSS4JOutInterceptor bean.

But in the outbound request, I got that:

```
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    <wsse:KeyIdentifier
        EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#ThumbprintSHA1">QgB9VjsaVwwYNx/MowOS058pegY=</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
```

So weirdly I got a Thumbprint keyIdentifier. Is it a bug or do I need to configure it differently?

PS.: here is the full applicationContext.xml:

```
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties" />

    <bean id="ProjectServices" class="primavera.ws.ProjectPortType"
        factory-bean="clientFactory" factory-method="create" />
    <bean id="clientFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceClass" value="primavera.ws.ProjectPortType" />
        <property name="address"
            value="http://port-128:8206/p6ws/services/ProjectService" />
        <property name="inInterceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="logIn" />
                <ref bean="signResponse" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="outInterceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="logOut" />
                <ref bean="saajOut" />
                <ref bean="signRequest" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="logIn" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
    <bean id="logOut" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
    <bean id="saajOut" class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor" />

    <bean id="signRequest" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp Signature Encrypt" />
                <entry key="user" value="username" />
                <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                <entry key="signatureUser" value="serverwsalias" />
                <entry key="encryptionUser" value="serverwsalias" />
                <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="main.ClientPasswordCallback" />
                <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="/crypt.properties"></entry>
                <entry key="signatureParts"
                    value="{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp;Body" />
                <entry key="encryptionPropFile" value="/crypt.properties"></entry>
                <entry key="encryptionParts"
                    value="{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}UsernameToken;Body" />
                <entry key="encryptionKeyIdentifier" value="EncryptedKeySHA1"></entry>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="signResponse" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="action" value="Encrypt" />
                <entry key="encryptionUser" value="serverwsalias" />
                <entry key="decryptionPropFile" value="/crypt.properties"></entry>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>asco</groupId>
    <artifactId>testPrimaveraWS</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <cxf.version>3.0.4</cxf.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>wsClient</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                    <packageName>primavera.ws</packageName>
                    <wsdlUrls>
                        <wsdlUrl>http://port-128:8206/p6ws/services/ProjectService?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                    </wsdlUrls>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You write it is the _full_ applicationContext.xml, but there is a closing `</beans>` without and opening `<beans>`.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this on the CXF mailing list here:

http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Apache-CXF-3-0-4-and-Wss4j-problem-with-KeyIdentifier-EncryptedKeySHA1-tp5754719p5754727.html